# t-student distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, distributions

I've got this problem:
[image]

Here, if $Z,W$ are independent random variables, and $Z$ has normal standart distribution and $W$ has $\chi^2$ with $n$ degrees of freedom, $T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{W}{n}}}$.
I don't expect to find any problems in $b$ and $c$ parts, but in $a$, I don't know how to find the conditional density. How could I?

Comment: Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: If you can figure out b, then you should have no problem with the conditional density, by re-arranging terms in b.